# Mac OS X open cv write a video file. Error

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

I'm new to opencv and its development. I'm taking camera feed and that feed i convert into avi format's video file. When i try to open that file using VLC player. Nothing is shown to me. please find below the code i used. Any help is appreciated.( File is writing into file but i think its problem with file formats )

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv){


       VideoCapture vcap(0);
    if(!vcap.isOpened()){
        cout << "Error opening video stream or file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

   // VideoWriter video("/Users/venushka/Desktop/pre/ou.avi",vcap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC),vcap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS),
                     // cv::Size(vcap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), vcap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)));

    const int fps = 30.0;
    vcap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, fps);


    VideoWriter video("/Users/venushka/Desktop/pre/ou.avi", vcap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC), fps,
                      cv::Size(vcap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), vcap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)));

    for(;;){

        Mat frame;
        vcap >> frame;
        video.write(frame);
        imshow( "Frame", frame );
        char c = (char)waitKey(33);
        if( c == 27 ) break;
    }
return 0;
    }
```

[image: image of video file]

Answer (score 0):

`CV_CAP_PROP_FPS` only works on videos as far as I know, from camera it will return 0.

Set your FPS manually as follows:

```
const int fps = 30.0;
vcap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, fps);

VideoWriter video("<path to avi>", vcap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FOURCC), fps,
                  cv::Size(vcap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), vcap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)));
```

Comment: Sorry ,still not working. The cap i processed cannot open via VLC player. Thank you.

Comment: I tried on my iMac and it works. Are height and width >0?